# How to crop/mask a shapefile by another shapefile R

Tags: r

I am trying to crop a shapefile containing rivers and streams (sf.streams)  by the extent of an AOI shapefile (shp.AOI) I already read in prior. I am not finding a tutorial on the web explaining this. Any help would be appreciated. I attached some code below that did not work due to me being new to R and to the sf package. I don't have any formal R training and I am learning as I am doing so sorry if this is a simple question or if I am wayyy off. I also don't know if I am supposed to be cropping and masking, I am confused on the two. What I want to do is remove any data outside the AOI to save on computing power and time because the datasets I am using are very large. THANKS!!!

```
shp.AOI <- readOGR(dsn="InputData/GIS/AOI", layer="AOI") %>% 
  spTransform(., crs.NAD83.UTM.Z10) %>% 
  tidy(.)

sf.streams <- 
  sf::st_read(file.path("InputData", "GIS", "Streams","Preprocessed","Rivers.shp"), 
              stringsAsFactors=F, crs=crs.NAD83.UTM.Z10) %>%
      st_transform(.,aoi=shp.AOI)
```

I also tried........

```
 sf.streams <- 
  sf::st_read(file.path("InputData", "GIS", "Streams","Preprocessed","Rivers.shp"), 
              stringsAsFactors=F, crs=crs.NAD83.UTM.Z10) %>%
      st_crop(.,aoi=shp.AOI)
```

Comment: What's not working? I can see that at least part of the problem is you are using `readOGR` and `st_read` to read shapefiles, and these two files use two different R packages and create incompatible objects. So using them together in anything else will fail. But you've not shown us any error messages...

Comment: Also, before adding anything to a pipe make sure the current pipe returns sensible data. Better still, drop the pipes and store intermediate results in new objects so you can inspect and check your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for st_intersection:

```
 sf.streams <- 
  sf::st_read(
file.path("InputData", "GIS", "Streams","Preprocessed","Rivers.shp"),
             stringsAsFactors=F, crs=crs.NAD83.UTM.Z10) %>%
      st_intersection(shp.AOI)
```